# How to JSON nested keys using groovy

Tags: groovy

I am having below code for creating JSON.

```
import groovy.json.*;

def input='{\"env\": {\"a\": 1,\"b\": 2,\"c\": 3,\"d\": 4}}';
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def inputJson= jsonSlurper.parseText(input);

def mapping = jsonSlurper.parseText("{}");


def NO2 = jsonSlurper.parseText("{}");
def CO2 = jsonSlurper.parseText("{}");
def SO2 = jsonSlurper.parseText("{}");
def CO = jsonSlurper.parseText("{}");

NO2["NO2"] = inputJson.env.c
mapping["ENVIRONMENT"] = NO2
CO2["CO2"] = inputJson.env.a
mapping["ENVIRONMENT"] = CO2
SO2["SO2"] = inputJson.env.d
mapping["ENVIRONMENT"] = SO2
CO["CO"] = inputJson.env.b
mapping["ENVIRONMENT"] = CO


def finalJson = new JsonBuilder(mapping).toPrettyString();

println finalJson
```

In the above code it is creating JSON like this:

```
{
    "ENVIRONMENT": {
        "CO": 2
    }
}
```

But I am not getting why it skipped CO2,NO2 and SO2.

The output I wanted:

```
{
    "ENVIRONMENT": {
        "CO2": 1,
        "CO":2,
        "NO2":3,
        "SO2":4
    }
}
```

Is there any way by using this method I colud get this JSON.

Thanks:)

Comment: Read your code again, carefully. You are overwriting `mapping["ENVIRONMENT"]` several times.

Comment: Then how I can add all the keys

Answer (score 0):

In java a map can have only unique keys. Usually the last `put` operation wins.

```
...
mapping["ENVIRONMENT"] = SO2
mapping["ENVIRONMENT"] = NO2
```

Also, your code is hor.. superfluous, really.

The way to do your stuff is:

```
import groovy.json.*

def input='{"env": {"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3,"d": 4}}' // no need to escape " in single-quoted litterals

def env = new JsonSlurper().parseText( input ).env

Map out = [ ENVIRONMENT:[
  NO2:env.c,
  CO2:env.a,
  SO2:env.d,
  CO:env.b,
] ]

String finalJson = JsonOutput.toJson out 

assert '{"ENVIRONMENT":{"NO2":3,"CO2":1,"SO2":4,"CO":2}}' == finalJson
```